# Converting a bitwise operation Java code to PHP

Tags: java, php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Hi there is a method for calculating some checksum which is written in Java. Here is the code:

```
01  public String getChecksum() {
02      String checkSumBuffer = getMessageHeader() + getConversationHeader() + getTransactionHeader() + operationInformation;
03      char[] res = new char[4];
04      for (int j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
05          for (int i = j; i < checkSumBuffer.length(); i = i + 4) {
06              res[j] = (char) (res[j] ^ checkSumBuffer.charAt(i));
07          }
08          res[j] = (char) ((~res[j]) & 0x00ff);
09      }
10      String strCheckSum = "";
11      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
12          strCheckSum = strCheckSum + Integer.toHexString((int) res[i]);
13      }
14      checksum = strCheckSum.toUpperCase();
15      return checksum;
16  }
```

and this is the PHP equivalent code:

```
00  public function getChecksum() {
01      $checkSumBuffer = $this->getMessageHeader() . $this->getConversationHeader() . $this->getTransactionHeader() . $this->operationInformation;
02      $res = array(0,0,0,0); // array with 4 elements
03      for ($j = 0; $j < count($res); $j++) {
04          for ($i = $j; $i < strlen($checkSumBuffer); $i = $i + 4) {
05              $res[$j] = $res[$j] ^ $checkSumBuffer[$i];
06          }
07          $res[$j] = ((~$res[$j]) & 0x00ff);
08      }
09      $strCheckSum = "";
10      for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
11          $strCheckSum = $strCheckSum . dechex($res[$i]);
12      }
13      $this->checksum = strtoupper($strCheckSum);*/
14      return $this->checksum;
15  }
```

But there is a problem in the PHP code. this is the output for each method:
java output: `C0E8F098`
php output: `FEFEFFFF`

I think the problem is that the `res` variable in java code is of type char, while in php code it is of type `int`. If that is the problem, How can I achieve that? I thought I can use [`chr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php%20%60chr%60) function which takes an `ASCII` code and returns the character. But it doesn't work and the output is: `0000`

What differences should I look in these codes to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make php use char also:

```
$res = array("\0", "\0", "\0", "\0"); // instead of $res = array(0,0,0,0);

$res[$j] = ((~$res[$j]) & "\xff"); // instead of $res[$j] = ((~$res[$j]) & 0x00ff);

$strCheckSum = $strCheckSum . bin2hex($res[$i]); // instead of $strCheckSum = $strCheckSum . dechex($res[$i]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Marek. You saved my damned day. Lots of kisses for you :). Thank you